# Saving Access Reports as PDF files

Tags: ms-access, pdf

I am currently in the process of generating a report in access which, once generated, should be saved to a save location to user puts in.

Here's my block of code.

```
ReportName = "Appraisal_" & Trim(Str(Year)) & "_" & Me.empnr & "_" & Veilig(Me.empnr) & "_" & Format(Now(), "YYYY_MM_DD_HH_MM_SS")
DoCmd.CopyObject , ReportName , acReport, "rpt_beoordelen"
DoCmd.OpenReport ReportName , acViewPreview, , "EmployeeNr='" & Me.empnr & "'  and year=" & Me.Year
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "", acFormatPDF, , True
DoCmd.Close acReport, ReportName
```

This generates and displays the report with the correct values. It asks for save location. And, once given, tries to save the file to given location. It quickly flashes a printing PDF to give location window.

After this the program stops. No file can be found at the given location and the report is still opened. Debugging the application shows me that

```
DoCmd.Close acReport, ReportName
```

is never reached. I do not get a errormessage and i have no clue what is going wrong. Could anyone give me a solution to this problem?

Comment: which access version you are running ?

Comment: What happens if you change the `OutputTo` line to this?: `DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "", acFormatPDF, , False`

Comment: @Hiten004 Microsoft Access 2010

Comment: @HansUp exactly the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are having trouble getting `DoCmd.OutputTo` to work with the "active object" by leaving `ObjectName` empty (ref: [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff192065.aspx)) then you could try this:

Open the "rpt_beoordelen" report and save its `Record Source` query as a saved Query named "rpt_beoordelen_base_data". Create a "rpt_beoordelen_data" saved Query with some generic SQL like...

```
SELECT * FROM rpt_beoordelen_base_data
```

...then make "rpt_beoordelen_data" the `Record Source` for the [rpt_beoordelen] report.

Now change the code from your question to something like this:

```
ReportName = "Appraisal_" & Trim(Str(Year)) & "_" & Me.empnr & "_" & Veilig(Me.empnr) & "_" & Format(Now(), "YYYY_MM_DD_HH_MM_SS")
DoCmd.CopyObject , ReportName , acReport, "rpt_beoordelen"
Dim cdb As DAO.Database
Set cdb = CurrentDb
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Set qdf = cdb.QueryDefs("rpt_beoordelen_data")
qdf.SQL = "SELECT * FROM rpt_beoordelen_base_data WHERE EmployeeNr='" & Me.empnr & "'  and year=" & Me.Year
Set qdf = Nothing
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, ReportName, acFormatPDF
```

That will change your invocation of `DoCmd.OutputTo` to one that does not depend on the "active object" and may yield the results you desire. (FWIW, it's the only way I've gotten this method to work for generating PDF versions of reports.)